# Average of grouped rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have the next table called BALL:

```
Id ...... Color ........... Month  
1 ........ blue ............ October
2 ........ red ............. January  
3 ........ green ........... September  
4 ........ red ............. October  
5 ........ red ............. March  
6 ........ blue ............ March  
7 ........ red ............. March
```

The query I want to do is: Show the average number of colors blue month by month.

So I want the next result:

```
October 0.5
January 0
September 0
March 0.33
```

I was thinking in something like:

```
SELECT BALL.Month, avg(BALL.Color) 
FROM BALL
WHERE BALL.Color = 'blue'
GROUP BY BALL.Month;
```

But It didn't work,

Comment: So, you want the percentage of blue balls each month? One idea: avg(colour='blue')

Comment: Your idea works

Comment: @Strawberry you should submit that as an answer so it can be accepted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this method

```
SELECT BALL.Month, avg(BALL.Color='Blue') 
FROM BALL    
GROUP BY BALL.Month;
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT MONTH , ROUND( AVG( color =  'blue' ) , 2 ) 
FROM  `balls` 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY MONTH

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. It is little complicated. But works

```
select t1.month,ifnull(t2.occur/t1.tot,0) as percentage from 
(select month, count(*) as tot from ball group by month) as t1
left join 
(select month, count(*) as occur from ball where color="blue" group by month) as t2 
on t1.month=t2.month
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f1fc/1

Comment: the sample output the OP included had months with percentage == 0, whereas yours only includes months with >0 ...

Comment: @SamOnela Corrected that

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.month,t1.mon_cnt,t2.col_cnt from  (select month,count(month) mon_cnt     from tab1 group by month) t1  join  (select month,count(month) col_cnt from tab1     where color='blue' group by month) t2 on (t1.month=t2.month);
```